# Como retornar dados de um evento pelo Graph API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Estou começando a testar integrações com o Facebook em meu site e ao tentar retornar informações de um evento utilizando o código que consta na [documentação da API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/event) recebo o seguinte erro:

`code: 104
 message: "An access token is required to request this resource."
 type: "OAuthException"`

sei que tenho que informar o token de acesso para a API retornar as informações (como visto no Graph Explorer) mas não sei como utilizá-lo via Javascript. Alguém poderia me passar um feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, tudo bem?!,

Dei uma lida rápida pela documentação, descobri esse link que tem exatamente o que você precisa:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started

Se tiver alguma dúvida posta de novo aqui..

vlw!

Comment: Excelente amigo, não tinha encontrado essa descrição ainda na API do Graph, meu erro foi não abrir as chaves do objeto para informar qual o "access_token". muito obrigado